# I am new to Jenkins and find that there are many ways to install jenkins. Which is the best way to use Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

There are many ways to use Jenkins

1) As a docker image (AWS)

2) or by downloading Jenkins package and running it (AWS)

3) or can have a physical machine and install Jenkins there.

Can you please help me which is the best way to have Jenkins?

Comment: It depends on platform, OS / operating system, which you need to run Jenkins on. So, "best" really depends on what your trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know kubernetes and already worked with EKS. The best way is install jenkins using helm and configure pipelines using Jenkinsfile.

So, jenkins-master will run on a pod and the workers will be started on pods during execution.

Helm charts:
https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins

Kubernetes Plugin:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin

Answer (score -2):

The best way I would suggest it run on individual servers on the AWS.

Comment: Why do you think so? Include additional details and reasoning to enhance your answer.

Comment: Jenkins is CI CD tool and If it's running on separate server on cloud it will be good that's What I feel and we can run as docker container aswell. What's your point

Comment: @cello's point was that to make for a good S/O answer, especially to an opinion-based question (which btw are normally closed aa opinion-based), is to provide context,, explanation and justification to back your opinion. That let's the OP determine the value of your opinion based on their needs and context.